# How to assign public router to docker group in bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create a scalable docker group and make it can be accessible to internet by assign a public IP address. But on where can I do this ?   In bluemix doc, it mentioned that there has a field named as "assign" but I can not find this field.

Comment: If you have the IP, can you try a `ice ip bind your.public.ip <containerID>`, and then access your app through `http://your.public.ip:port` with port being the one you have mapped at the `docker run -p x:port` stage?

Answer (score 3):

On the IBM Containers service, only a single container (not part of a scalable group) can have a public IP address. For those, you can [see the documentation about managing IP addresses](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ips_ov.html). If you are using the web interface, when you create a container there's a **Public IP address** drop-down that will let you either assign an existing IP address or request and bind a new one. As @VonC commented, if you expose those ports you can access your container via the expected `http://dd.ddd.ddd.ddd:port`

For a scalable group, you can't do a single public IP address, but you can assign a route (for example, https://my-container.mybluemix.net) that is public, secure (HTTPS), and will distribute incoming requests *to one published port* on the containers in the group. **You can only publish one port for a group**. The route will send traffic to that port automatically, so for example if your containers host a web service on port 8080, *don't* try to access them with the port in the URL like `https://my-container.mybluemix.net:8080`.

**Update October 2016**: It is now possible to assign a public IP address to a container group when you create a group. To do so, you must have already requested an IP address (`cf ic ip request`); then when you make a group you specify the public IP address with the `--ip` option, for example:

`cf ic group create --name="my_group_with_an_IP" -p 9080 --ip xxx.xx.xxx.xxx registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty:latest`

Even with an IP address, you can still only expose one port for a group.